# Getting multiple details in contact information from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angular and trying to create a contact form where I will get name, multiple mobile number and multiple email address.

Trying to implement the below object in form

```
 $scope.contactInfo = [{
    name: 'Sam',
    mobile: [123, 456, 789],
    email: 'sam123@gmail.com'
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    mobile: [123],
    email: ['sam123@gmail.com', 'john@gmail.com']
  }];
```

I have tried with bootstrap to create form like [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2j69wv2p/1/). But on click of save button how can I get all the input values from my form in the format which I have mentioned inside save function

```
$scope.save = function(){
  //On click of save button trying to get something lik this
   $scope.contactInfo = [{
    name: 'Sam',
    mobile: [123, 456, 789],
    email: 'sam123@gmail.com'
  }, {
    name: 'John',
    mobile: [123],
    email: ['sam123@gmail.com', 'john@gmail.com']
  }];
```

Comment: That's the thing. You don't have to get the input data. just get the $scope data.

Comment: Are you using angular 4 ?

Comment: @JorgeMejia I am using angular v 1.5.7